# why google account id and password not working sometime and use 2nd step verification after gives a key in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, gmail-api

Here are some required detail about configuration in `.env` file and this is working also.

Many times laravel frameworks is accepted only **Google 2nd step verification after gives a keys** instead of **Google id password**, so please anyone know why not working Google id password and 2nd step key working ?

My problem is **Google Password** or **2nd step verification key**, Please help me.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=google ID
MAIL_PASSWORD=google ID Password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Please late me know if some needful information was missing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use like this one:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=id
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Have edited the question as per my question can you please look at this. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to allow "unsecure" app access your Gmail. See: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Then, if port 465 with ssl does not work for you, try with 587 and tls.

This always works for me:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=<email_add>
MAIL_FROM_NAME="<name>"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_USERNAME=<gmail>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<password>
```

p/s: use Google SMTP to dev ENV only